# Firestore security rules allow user access to their data

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I want to write a rule like this:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /users/{userId}/{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth.uid == userId;
    }
  }
}
```

That is, I want to allow all read and write operations to all of a user's data if that user *is the authenticated user*.

Unfortunately that does not work.  I get an error specifying that I don't have permission to access the data.

Comment: Are you having issues with that? Or what is your question?

Comment: @Gerardo I worked it out.  Wasn't giving access to the actual doc, just the subdocs.  It's very hard to debug rules at present.

Answer (score 6):

This code solved the problem:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /users/{userId} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth.uid == userId;
      match /{document=**} {
        allow read, write: if request.auth.uid == userId;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I think it's because you need to grant access to `/users/{userId}`, as well as `/users/{userId}/{anyDoc=**}`.

Comment: Just for reference, this is from the docs: "Recursive wildcards cannot match an empty path, so match /cities/{city}/{document=**} will match documents in subcollections but not in the cities collection, whereas match /cities/{document=**} will match both documents in the cities collection and subcollections." https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-structure#hierarchical_data

Comment: @Gerardo Thanks for the ref!  I guess `/users/{document=**}` wouldn't work in my case because I need to get the user ID for the auth.  I thought it could be done with request.path but it's not working.  Any idea why `service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /users/{document=**} {
     // path[6] is uid
     // eg. /projects/projectId/databases/(default)/documents/users/{uid}
      allow read, write: if request.auth.uid == request.path[6];
    }
  }
}` doesn't work?

Comment: Have you tried with resource.id?  the paht contains the complete string and no just the id of the documen, that's why it fails when being compared to the user's uid https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/security/#firestore-resource

Comment: @Gerardo resource.id won't work because the document may not be a user document (eg `/user/{uid}`), it could be a sub-document of user, eg. `/user/{uid}/subCol/{subColDocId}`.  If is were a sub-doc then `resource.id` would return subColDocId instead of uid.
I would have thought path could work, for example path[0] should be 'projects', path[2] should be 'databases', path[5] should be 'users', etc. but it doesn't seem to be working.

Answer (score 1):

From the [official documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions):

> Another common pattern is to make sure users can only read and write
>   their own data:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    // Make sure the uid of the requesting user matches name of the user
    // document. The wildcard expression {userId} makes the userId variable
    // available in rules.
    match /users/{userId} {
      allow read, update, delete: if request.auth.uid == userId;
      allow create: if request.auth.uid != null;
    }
  }
}
```

> If your app uses Firebase Authentication, the request.auth variable
>   contains the authentication information for the client requesting
>   data.

Comment: but where does this come from ---> match /users/{userId} ?  is it from the users data collection in Firestore?  is it from the list of authenticated users that has the default name users ?  I can't get this to work for anything and I've tried so many different combinations it's making my head spin

Comment: @LinusBicker /users/{userId} is a collection that you can create to mirror the users in your Firebase Authentication. You can easily do this by setting up Firebase triggers when a user has been created. However, this was just a generic example, you don't have to do this. You could have a collection of pizza documents with a userId inside of them. Then, you can do exactly the same check as above.

Answer (score 1):

Please note that this *only* works if you have made a 'users' table in your database and populated it with users that are known to your application (possibly copied from FireBase's users section Authentication/users in the webconsole).

AfaIcs you cannot refer to the Firestore authenticated users table this way. I found this lack of information very confusing since all examples and Firestore documentation make you believe that you can access the users created through the webconsole this way, invariably  resulting in an 'access denied' messages when trying to read from a users table...