# Firestore rules to restrict users to read/write only their data

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I am trying to restrict the users to their own data, but currently the data is being shared. I done some research ([SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49249667/4091828), [Firebase Docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-structure#hierarchical_data)), but they have not worked for me. I could've possibly overlooked the solution.

DB rules:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }

    match /users/{userId} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth.uid == userId;

      match /{document=**} {
        allow read, write: if request.auth.uid == userId;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

DB data:

```
users: [{
    {userId}: {
        email: "...",
        fullName: "...",
        uId: "..." // same as key
        tasks: [{
            {unique taskId}: {
                id: "...", // same as key
                desc: "...",
                priority: 3,
                completed: false
            }
        }]
    }
}]
```

Data query (Angular):

```
this.afStore
    .collection(`users`)
    .doc(`${this.authService.getUserId()}`)
    .collection(`tasks`, ref => {
            return ref
                .where('completed', '==', completed)
                .orderBy(sortField, sortOrder);
        }).snapshotChanges().pipe(
                ...
        );
```

Is this a rules issue, or data/query issue? I think I am missing something minor with the rules...

Answer (score 2):

This rule of yours:

```
match /{document=**} {
  allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
}
```

Is being unconditionally applied to **all** documents in your database.  When a rule allows access to a document it **always** grants access to it, no matter what other rules are in play.

What that rule is saying is that **all** users have read and write access to **all** documents in your database.  If this isn't what you want, remove the rule entirely.  Replace it with only rules that allow access to just the documents that should be allowed access to just the users who should be able to do so.

To be perfectly clear - you can't have a rule that allows access to a document be later revoked by another rule.  If **any** rule allows access, then that access will be allowed, no matter what the other rules say.

Comment: Thank you for the response. After removing that rule, it says "FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions." when trying to add tasks for most users.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar case, and here is the rule set that works for me:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /users/{userId} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth.uid == userId;
      match /{document=**} {
        allow read, write: if request.auth.uid == userId;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It is worth noting that I used `rules_version = '2'`, as it changes the behavior of the [recursive wildcard](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-structure#recursive_wildcards)